# Variable in other script in C

Tags: c, variables

How can I use a variable from another script in C?

Something like in this example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
int one = 1;
return 0;
}
```

Another script:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
printf();// Print the variable "one" here
return 0;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do note that in C we generally don't call source code "scripts," as C is not generally used as a scripting language.

Comment: simple answer, 'no'. Real answer 'yes' but very very complicated and probably not what you are looking for. (Please dont say 'scripts', these are programs). Two c programs like this are totally independent of each other

Comment: It's hard to understand what exactly you want, since "script" is not an estabilished term in C++. You could compile two source files into a single executable, but that would require removing one of the two `main`s. You could then use a global variable from one file in the other. Is that what you want?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have written this, it is not possible, as the variable `one` is a local variable of the function `main`. If you want to share variables between files, you may define a function to pass the value you want to share, or declare a global variable that you use directly from both functions.

Using a global variable would look like this:

```
// First file

extern void print_one(void);

int one = 1;

int main(void) {
    print_one();

    return 0;
}

// Second file

extern int one;

void print_one(void) {
    printf("%d\n", one);
}
```

Do also note that if you declare functions with the same name (in this case `main`, you won't be able to link these two source files together, as the linker won't know which version of the `main` function you want.

Comment: Also, as a short note, if you mean sharing variables between different programs, you can't share them directly. It would be best to use some form of IPC (inter process communication) depending on your Operating System.